# Wireless/wifi network is not working on ubuntu 12.04 - lenovo z50-70

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I just ran below script

**wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script**

and attached the information here at

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9999146/

can anybody help me to fix this wireless issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes, first get rid of the incorrect driver
`sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common`
Then install backports

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.18.1/backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz
tar -xf backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz
cd ~/backports-3.18.1-1
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

And you will need firmware so `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`
Reboot

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you so much. I was trying to fix this issue for the past 3 weeks.You saved my time....Excellent!!!!.....

Comment: This works for the current kernel, when your kernel gets updated you will need to `cd ~/backports-3.18.1-1` then `make clean` then `make defconfig-rtlwifi` then `make` and finally `sudo make install`