# How to connect a bluetooth keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, ideapad

I'm trying to pair a bluetooth keyboard to my Lenovo Ideapad Z70-50.

```
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
```

But nothing is found, even though my keyboard is in discovery mode. The device works, since I can pair it with my tablet. I'm trying to provide below details of my set up.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
$ uname -a
Linux zen 3.16.0-30-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 12 22:06:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci  | grep Net
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

$ lsmod | grep bt
btcoexist              50429  1 rtl8723be
btusb                  32448  0 
bluetooth             446190  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm

$ rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
4: phy1: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no

$ sudo hciconfig 
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
      BD Address: 00:71:CC:1B:13:3C  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
      UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
      RX bytes:1363 acl:0 sco:0 events:99 errors:0
      TX bytes:1286 acl:0 sco:0 commands:92 errors:0

$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[    3.012078] usb 2-7: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   26.753961] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   26.753985] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   26.753991] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   26.753992] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   26.753999] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   27.540874] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   27.540878] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   27.540889] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   27.761547] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   27.761558] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   27.761563] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:055e Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader  Controller
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 0b95:772a ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772A Fast Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 2001:3c15 D-Link Corp. DWA-140 RangeBooster N Adapter(rev.B3) [Ralink RT5372]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What is the result of `lsusb`

Comment: added at the bottom. BTW I'm running Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the realtek device that is part of the wifi, see `Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.`
This device doesn't work but causes issues with other USB bluetooth dongles when you try to use them.  Later today I can build you a btusb.ko module that will ignore the Realtek as I did [Disable internal RTL8723 bluetooth](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262775)

But make it for your kernel as the one I posted there will only work for 3.13.0-44
There is a small chance that this will work for you after a reboot

```
echo "install btusb /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install btusb && echo '0bda b728' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/remove_id" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/bcmbtusb.conf
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, I will try this when I get home tonight (it's on my home laptop)

Comment: might be easier than that if you don't use the Realtek card for wifi.  See if the internal wifi can be disabled in BIOS

Comment: I've disabled the card in bios and followed instructions in the linked post. now hcitool scan says "no such device". rfkill list shows ideapad_bluetooth and not the hci0 entry any more. I guess probably that's OK if the device or the driver is buggy. I suppose I should try to buy a bluetooth dongle then.

Comment: Your wifi card can work with the instructions from http://askubuntu.com/questions/580551/wireless-wifi-network-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-04-lenovo-z50-70/580578?noredirect=1#comment803536_580578 from my answer starting with the wget command.  Is the 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth not a true bluetooth device?

Comment: That's for the main mouse/keyboard. I'm not sure if it can also used for other bluetooth devices. I've tried instructions, however I get some warnings and after an error 
    *** Can't find default configuration "defconfigs/rtfwifi"!
    Makefile.real:41: recipe for target 'defconfig-rtfwifi' failed
    make[1]: *** [defconfig-rtfwifi] Error 1
    Makefile:40: recipe for target 'defconfig-rtfwifi' failed
    make: *** [defconfig-rtfwifi] Error 2

Comment: You might need some other things installed `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and then you should be able to run the commands

Comment: It likely still sees the microft device as bluetooth but not the realtek

Comment: I had build-essential already and also kernel headers.

Comment: Found issue, command is `make defconfig-rtlwifi` not rtfwifi

Comment: ooops of course... sorry! I am trying now

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for all your effort. The installation worked (and I had already linux-firmware). After reboot I didn't have the module rtlwifi installed, so I did `sudo modprobe rtlwifi`. Despite that `hcitool scan` says `Device is not available: No such device`. Maybe because I've disabled the card at boot?
`lsmod | egrep "rtl|blue"` --> `rtlwifi            105358  0 
mac80211           576405  1 rtlwifi
cfg80211           508913  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
compat              14427  3 cfg80211,mac80211,rtlwifi
bluetooth          446190  >10 bnep,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc        18702  1 bluetooth`

Comment: Enable in bios and it should work

Comment: I have enabled it, but `hciconfig -a` shows nothing. `rfkill list` now shows ideapad_wlan (soft blocked), ideapad_bluetooth (not blocked) and phy0 (soft blocked). hci0 is not there any more.

Comment: Try the FN keyboard combo to enable wifi and the soft block should be gone

Comment: yes or I can rfkill unblock all, but the issue as described above is that no bluetooth device is detected by hciconfig, even though rfkill shows a ideapad_bluetooth, which is not blocked, as said above...

Comment: Get a USB bluetooth device like the GBU421 as I think it works out of the box in linux.  I have a few of the GBU USB bluetooth devices and the GBU521 is the only one that took some tinkering to make it function.

Comment: Ok.. I will try this one... thank you so much for all help http://www.amazon.co.uk/IOGEAR-GBU521-Bluetooth-Micro-Adapter/dp/B007GFX0PY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1423069300&sr=8-1&keywords=iogear+bluetooth