# wifi network drop on lenovo g50-70

Tags: wireless

I'm having problems with my WiFi on a Lenovo G50-70. After a certain time WiFi drops the network. then I have to go for rebooting the whole system to get it back again. please suggest me how to fix it.

when I tried to know the hardware version it shows as below:

```
sudo lshw | grep [Ww]ireless
     description: Wireless interface
     product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=3.13.0-45-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem and I followed the instructions of user241073.
Actually things became better: now when connection is lost I can "simply" reconnect from network manager. However, it is not so good.
Have Anyone a definitive solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.18.1/backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz
tar -xf backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz
cd ~/backports-3.18.1-1
make defconfig-rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and enjoy as it should work in 14.04 just like it did in 12.04

[Ask Ubuntu 12.04 z50-70](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580551/wireless-wifi-network-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-04-lenovo-z50-70/580578#580578)

Be sure to read my comment about what to do when your kernel updates...you will know when it happens as your wifi should give you problems again

Comment: can i know the actual root cause for this?

Comment: I don't know the exact cause of the drop or what was the fix, here is a link to the changelog http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth-next.git/log/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi

Comment: i followed the above steps and installed all the modules. then after reboot it was not even connecting to any of the available network. so i had to revert back :(

Comment: I wonder if chili's answer here still works http://askubuntu.com/questions/389268/no-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-13-10 I know it is kept up to date

Answer (score 0):

I had been struggling with this issue for months. Here's what finally worked for me and seems to be working for others on 14.04:

**Download the latest driver (you might have to install git first)**

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

**Change into the new directory you just created**

```
cd rtlwifi_new
```

**Compile and install the new driver**

```
make
sudo make install
```

**Edit the settings for the driver**

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

It's probably a good idea to take a look at that file to make sure that worked. Some people say the "swlps=0" part of the command above is unnecessary. I'm not sure but it doesn't seem to be hurting anything.

Reboot.

**The next time your system updates the kernel, you may have to do this part again:**

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

I'd be curious to hear if others have tried this on releases other than 14.04 with success.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The only way that worked for me, was detailed in the bug report at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...x/+bug/1320070

at the end there is a link to a script which disables your bluetooth (and maybe other things)..... This fixed the problem for me ... But obviously stopped bluetooth working.