# My wifi is not functioning properly on my Lenovo Z50-70 using a Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I am newbie in using Linux.
When I installed UBuntu 14.04, I found wifi problem with my Lenovo Z50-70.
After connecting to a wireless network it works for a brief period of time, then, although it shows a stable connection, I can't access any website whatsoever.

wireless-info as below:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10661824/

I have follow all the step answer 1 in this question [Wireless/wifi network is not working on ubuntu 12.04 - lenovo z50-70](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580551/wireless-wifi-network-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-04-lenovo-z50-70)

But when I make install, it shows 
Note:
You may or may not need to update your initramfs, you should if
any of the modules installed are part of your initramfs. To add
support for your distribution to do this automatically send a
patch against "update-initramfs.sh". If your distribution does not
require this send a patch with the '/usr/bin/lsb_release -i -s'
("Ubuntu") tag for your distribution to avoid this warning.

Your backported driver modules should be installed now.
Reboot.

I already Reboot but the wifi problem still there

Answer (score 0):

The only other idea I have after the backports are installed is

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723.conf
```

Reboot